# How to change the width of an HTML upload field with CSS?

Tags: html, css, forms, upload

I can change the width of an upload field with the size attribute:

```
<input type="file" size="20">
```

But CSS's `width`, which works fine for regular input fields and other forms controls, seems to have no effect here, even on Firefox:

```
<input type="file" style="width: 20em">
```

Is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: did you try adding a semicolon after 20em ?

Comment: @flyfishr64: that *shouldn't* make a diff

Comment: @Mark, ah the old "shouldn't" versus "doesn't, does it?" debate... =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will help but this article seems to go quite in-depth into various ways of styling a file-input:

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Comment: @Michael, this is an excellent resource. Not as simple as adding some CSS, but it will do the trick. Thank you for sharing that.